# How to get pop up window in part of phone like the image

Tags: android, kotlin

I am trying to make my own alarm app and want to have a partial view open up when an alarm activates no matter where in the phone I am at, like the image I am including. Can I please get some tips on how I would do this, do I start an activity through an intent with the alarm manager? Or can I just start a fragment? Also, how do I get it to just be the little window, I prefer that, and do not want to launch a full screen view. Apologies that I do not know much, I don't have anyone else to ask for advice. I am using kotlin, Thank you. [image]

Comment: This just looks like a notification?

Comment: It may be, I am not sure. I wan to be able to add custom buttons to my pop up that will be capable of accessing the apps data base to modify or delete alarms.

Comment: Yes you'll just need a notification, I would recommend doing your research (@JohnDoe has done the Google search for you) and then come back if you have any problems. Good luck!

Comment: thank you for the input. it was a simple answer but I didn't know!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's just a notification that has a button.

You'll find everything here: https://developer.android.com/training/notify-user/build-notification

To add a Button: https://developer.android.com/training/notify-user/build-notification#Actions

Just a hint: If you change the behaviour of your channel, clear your appdata or choose another id (Or even better: delete your channel via notificationManager if it's not needed anymore). Otherwise the changes will not be applied.